# Updating Inactive Window

Tags: swift, macos

How do you update an inactive window?

I have an application with 2 windows. One is for user input and is the main window by default. The second is just to display values in NSTextFields and is generally inactive. I'm having trouble updating elements in the second window.

Here's minimal code which reproduces the problem (Swift 3):

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var logArea: NSScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var logText: NSTextView!

    var windowController: NSWindowController
    var vc: ViewController2

    @IBAction func runButton(_ sender: Any) {
        displayText(text: "Running")
        vc.updateInput(value: 1.0005)
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
        windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "WindowID") as! NSWindowController
        windowController.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        vc = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "ViewID") as! ViewController2
        vc.loadView()
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }

    func displayText(text: String) {
        logText.textStorage?.append(NSAttributedString(string: text + "\n"))
    }

}

class ViewController2: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var input0: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func updateButton(_ sender: Any) {
        updateInput(value: 1.0)
    }

    func updateInput(value: Double) {
        if input0.doubleValue == 1.0 { input0.doubleValue = 0.0 }
        else { input0.doubleValue = value }
    }

}
```

`vc.updateInput(value: 1.0005)` in ViewController doesn't work, but `updateButton` in ViewController2 does.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Added minimal complete code to reproduce problem.

Comment: Well, it looks like you've got two ViewController2 instances: the `vc` you create and retain in ViewController by saying `storyboard.instantiateController` is not the same ViewController2 that the storyboard _itself_ loads from the storyboard and populates the _actual_ window that you're looking at.

Comment: Ahh. I see. Can you recommend where to look for best practice to get reference to 2nd window? I've been searching. This is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Well you could start by asking the NSApp for its windows, but really the answer probably depends on how this window got created in the first place. If the window controller in your code is creating and showing the window, that should give you access to the window and its contents.